# antlr match any character except

Tags: string, char, antlr, match

I have the following deffinition of fragment:

```
fragment CHAR   :'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'\n'|'\t'|'\\'|EOF;
```

Now I have to define a lexer rule for string. I did the following :

```
STRING   : '"'(CHAR)*'"'
```

However in string I want to match all of my characters except the new line '\n'. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll also need to exclude `"` besides line breaks. Try this:

```
STRING : '"' ~('\r' | '\n' | '"')* '"' ;
```

The `~` negates char-sets.

> ut I want to negate only the new line from my CHAR set

No other way than this AFAIK:

```
STRING : '"' CHAR_NO_NL* '"' ;

fragment CHAR_NO_NL : 'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'\t'|'\\'|EOF;
```

Comment: Well sorry I am new to antlr ... what I am asking is : I previously defined string as a sequence of CHARs. In your deffinition of STRING I can't see where did u put CHAR. So how the program will know that it should take everything from CHARS except the new line character?

Comment: Yes but I want to negate only the new line from my CHAR set .. in your case I take everything except the new line